# Cannot find symbol `ResolvingDataSource` from com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ResolvingDataSource

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x, cannot-find-symbol

Title says it all. ExoPlayer should have this. Just look at this page: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/ResolvingDataSource.html

But when I import `import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ResolvingDataSource` at the top of my class it lights up with red underline. And when I try to do:

```
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(
                new ResolvingDataSource.Factory(
                    new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this,getString(R.string.app_name))),
                    // Provide just-in-time URI resolution logic.
                    (DataSpec dataSpec) -> dataSpec.withUri(resolveUri(dataSpec.uri))
                )
            ).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(link));
```

`ReolvingDataSource` lights up with red underline. I also have this in my app build.gradel:
`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.1'`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the library to latest version [2.11.8](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.8'
```

Third party libraries always change, so keep track its official sites.